# Redis Monitor using Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: redis, grafana, prometheus

I have installed redis in a server

I wish to monitor redis via Prometheus and Grafana

Installed redis_exporter in the redis installed server using docker

```
 $ docker pull oliver006/redis_exporter
 $ docker run -d --name redis_exporter -p 9121:9121 oliver006/redis_exporter
```

Checked the redis_exporter **running status** in the server.

Added   the redis installed and redis exporter installed IP in prometheus.yml file in Grafana Server

```
 - job_name: 'redis_exporter'
    target_groups:
      - targets: ['IP:9121']
        labels:
          alias: redis
```

**Restarted** Prometheus in Grafana server

Checked the status in prometheus status page 
It shows **UP** for the redis server **IP:9121** mentioned in the prometheus.yml

**In Grafana :**

I have imported **Prometheus Redis** dashboard;(https://grafana.com/dashboards/763)

But data is not loading in the dashboard. Also the IP is not listed in the dashboard

Comment: Have you configured the prometheus datasource under Grafana Menu > Datasources > Prometheus?

Comment: yes configured it.

Comment: Any error outputted to the javascript console?

Comment: no error outputed in `prometheus.log` file

Comment: If you press F12 on your browser it will open up developer tools. Have a look at the console and see if there are any errors there. JavaScript won't output to the prometheus.log file.

Comment: no errors... console page is empty

Comment: Any errors on the network tab of developer tools?

Comment: How do you run Prometheus and Grafana? eg. with docker-compose?

Comment: No , Prometheus : `nohup ./prometheus > prometheus.log 2>&1 &` ; node_exporter : `./node_exporter &` ; Grafana : `service grafana-server start` ;

Comment: Have you checked if you were receiving metrics on prometheus db? Query "redis_uptime_in_seconds"

Comment: Also, I'd check the Targets in Prometheus installation

Comment: The ip are extracted from label `addr` of metric `redis_up`. Do you have such a metric/label ? The dashboard may rely on a metric relabel.

Comment: Note that if redis is running on the host, you should launch the docker with `--network host`

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check here:

1. Try this url and see if you're able to get the metrics.

```
curl -s "<redis_exporter>:9121/scrape?target=redis://<redis_instance>:6379"
```

2. Update the grafana dashboard variables from **`label_values(redis_up, addr)`** to **`label_values(redis_up, instance)`**

Comment: In addtion, on each panel of the Redis Exporter in grafana, do not forget to change the "address" to "instance" in the query.

Answer (score 0):

In case you set a password authentication for redis, need to supply a Redis password to `redis-exporter`

```
sudo docker run -d --name redis_exporter -p 9121:9121  oliver006/redis_exporter --redis.addr=redis://10.0.0.175:6379  --redis.password=redis_password_here
```